# faster getfiles in directory

Tags: vb.net, directoryinfo, getfiles

I have some code that has to search about 30000 files in several subdirectories to see if any files with a particular extension still exists.  It is running across a network to an iSeries share.  Any suggestion to make this faster.

```
Dim _cnt As Int16 = _di.GetFiles("*." + row("extension"), SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
                    If _cnt > 0 Then
                        Dim _msg As String = _dir + " still has " + _cnt.ToString() + " " + row("extension")
                        MessageBox.Show(_msg, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                        ts_StatusLabel.Text = _msg
                        Return
                    End If
```

Also is there a way to stop the search on the first hit?

Thank you.

Comment: So you don't need a list just a single file or none? Directory.EnumerateFiles can break on the first match

Answer (score 4):

To just know if a file with a particular extension is present in the folder structure you could use [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Any()`. This starts the enumeration immediately without waiting to load first all files with the specified extension.

```
Dim extFound = _di.EnumerateFiles("*." & row("extension"), _
                                  SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any()
If extFound Then
   Console.WriteLine("File with specific extension found")
End If
```

Of course this doesn't return the count of files with that extension but it just informs if a file with the specified extension exists.

If you need a count then you could use the `Count()` extension. But then you need to wait until the whole search is completed and so it is not very different from your current code.

```
Dim _cnt = _di.EnumerateFiles("*." + row("extension"), _
                              SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()
If _cnt Then
   Console.WriteLine("Found " & _cnt & " file/s")
End If
```

For what it worth, a simple benchmark on my `Microsoft Visual Studio` folder (37000 files) searching for files with EXE extension requires  960 milliseconds for Count() and it is not measurable (0 milli) for Any() (On an SSD disk)

Comment: That is great timings.  I'm seeing up to 10 minutes.  It must be network issues.

Comment: Well as I have said _for what it worth_ the conditions are remarkably different